# While loop permanently refreshes? | PHP

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have the problem, that my `while(true)` loop permanently loads the page. It doesn't really load at all, it's just infinitely loading. This is my code:

```
                <?php 
                echo $cid='<span class="cid" id="result"></span>'; 
                ?>

               <?php

                    //if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 
                    while(true) {

                        $str = $cid;

                        $DOM = new DOMDocument;
                        $DOM->loadHTML($str);

                        $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
                        $span_list = '';

                        for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
                            $item = $items->item($i);

                            if($item->getAttribute('class') == 'cid'){
                                $span_list = $item->nodeValue;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        echo 'hehe' . $span_list;
                        
                    }

                ?>
```

Basicly I just want to permanently refresh the var. So I can display the (right, not outdated) value in HTML code. Hope someone can help me, kind regards.

Comment: Use JS or refresh the page.

Comment: You are going to want to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) for something like this. It will allow you to pull the latest values as often as you need, and update the page (without needing to refresh the entire page).

Comment: @brombeer Lol, didn't think about that... but I don't want to refresh the page. I just wan't to repeat the php code to refresh the var.

Comment: Use JS/AJAX as suggested then

Comment: I think I couldn't use js because I want to call a php function. But how do I create a while loop in ajax, is that even possible? I don't find an answer on google...

Comment: EssXTee posted a link to an AJAX guide. You could send an AJAX request every second. Or, use websockets to inform the client when the value of your variable has changed

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the concept somehow. Ajax is just a way for js code to send a http request to your server (which can then run some php code and return a response). The only difference compared to refreshing the whole page is that this happens in the background while your existing page stays as it is. When you get the response from the server you can then use JS code to update only the bits of the page  you need to.

Comment: Ok, thank y'all very much : )